# MultipartFile always null Spring MVC return Response 400 for Upload Excel

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

I have a problem when uploading using multipartfile. Always return response 400. Required request part `files` is not present. I have tried many ways. but none worked

i have tried to register CommonsMultipartResolver. but still didnt work for me.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewFormReportUpload.html",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadFormPage(@ModelAttribute("viewForm") ViewFormDownload viewForm,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile files, BindingResult result) throws IOException {

    //some code
}
```

```
<form:input path="files" type="file" id="file" name="files" accept=".xls,.xlsx" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Your input is named `files` you are expecting a parameter named `file`. Different names hence an error.

Comment: i know. that i have already changed, but im still got error,

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form:input path="files" type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx"  class="form-control" />
```